# I have 3 Data tables in one page i need select one in each Table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying following it selecting from only one datatable

```
selectFirstRow(window.document.forms["irsf-form"]);
```

i have id's for each table "test_config","uma","example".

i had tried

```
selectFirstRowInTable(document.getElementById("irsf-form:test_config"));
selectFirstRowInTable(document.getElementById("irsf-form:uma"));
selectFirstRowInTable(document.getElementById("irsf-form:example"));
```

I have Script in that

```
function selectFirstRowInTable(tableObj) {

            var tbodyObj = tableObj.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var inputObjs = tbodyObj.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var tempChild = null;
            var firstRow=-1;
            for(var i=0;i<inputObjs.length;++i) {
            tempChild = inputObjs[i];

                if(tempChild.type == 'radio') {
                    if ( firstRow < 0 ) {
                firstRow = i;
                tempChild.checked = true;
            } else {
                tempChild.checked = false;
            }
            }
            }
    }
```

Not getting the value by id when i try getElementById

```
    <h:dataTable  binding="#{iRSFConfigBean.table}" border="1" rowClasses="evenRows,oddRows" id="test_config" name = "test"
rules="all" headerClass="standardTableHeader" styleClass="standardTable" value="#{iRSFConfigBean.configList}" var="config">
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: I am trying that one but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you:

```
$('table').find("tr:first")
```

Comment: i have 3 data table

Comment: i know. you try to test that code in your project, or you can create sample page with 3 table and use console to test this code

Comment: Okay may i know when my getElementById is not taking value.
                                <h:dataTable  binding="#{iRSFConfigBean.table}" border="1" rowClasses="evenRows,oddRows" id="test_config" name = "test"
rules="all" headerClass="standardTableHeader" styleClass="standardTable" value="#{iRSFConfigBean.configList}" var="config">
same id used